# Indentation Wrong Second line in Titleframe Goettingen theme (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, spacing, horizontal-alignment, themes, frame-title

I'm coming here looking for help because I've tried in every way to correct the error in the attached figure. When dealing with a long title, the second line suffers an unnecessary indentation. I wanted to make the second row line up equally with the first row. I'm using the Goettingen theme.

[image]

Before I made some changes to the layout of the Goettingen theme.
Although extensive, but this is the best way to more accurately report my problem. I suspect the fix for this issue may be associated with

> \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace{-0.4cm}\insertframetitle}

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme[left,width=1.5cm]{Goettingen}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}% Use a file in the directory solutions instead.
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left] 
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{%
    output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

% Vertical displacement frame title
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.3cm}}{\vspace*{0.0cm}}

% Horizontal displacement frame title
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace{-0.4cm}\insertframetitle}

% Color scheme for outer elements: use background colors
\usecolortheme{default} % beaver - whale - default

% Layout scheme for inner elements: rounded elements
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded} 

% Color scheme for inner elements: use foreground colors
\usecolortheme{orchid} % orchid

% Itemize items: default (triangle), circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

% Enumerate items: default, circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]

% Enumerate sections/subsections in table contents: default, circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

% Outline: default, sections numbered, subsections numbered, circle, square, ball, ball unnumbered
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

% General blocks:
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]

% Title page:
%\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounde=true]

% Part page:
\setbeamertemplate{part page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

% Navigation symbols:
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%font size sections/subsections in table contents
\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\normalsize}

% Default color font for sections/subsections
\definecolor{structure}{rgb}{51,51,178}


\date{}

%======================START DOCUMENT=======================

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Anomalias, Filtragem e Significância Estatística}

    
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the frame title in a `parbox`.

For this theme, the sidebar has a width of 2 cm, so this

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace{-0.4cm}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm}{\insertframetitle}}
```

will achieve the desired result

[image: a]

**UPDATE** after follow up question

To displace the title downwards add `\vspace{<lenght>}`

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{1cm}\hspace{-0.4cm}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm}{\insertframetitle}}
```

**or**  use

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{1cm}}{\vspace*{0.0cm}}
```

To change the baseline skip it is needed to modify the font of the frame title

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size*={14}{14}}
```

where it is used `size*={<font size>}{<baseline skip>}`.

Typically, the baseline skip is 1.2 times the font size.

[image: b]

Comment: Regarding the indentation, the solution was perfect. However, I noticed that the spacing between the lines was exaggerated. Another observation is that the vertical displacement is not being obeyed, e.g. \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.3cm}}{\vspace*{0.0cm}}

Comment: @Wendell Fialho Please see the updated answer.